# Capifony shared vendors composer install

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, capifony

I'm trying to configure Capifony to make a simple `composer install` in my shared vendor directory at each `deploy`. Unlike the [default behavior](http://capifony.org/#symfony2-deployment) running `composer update` (which I surely don't want !)

```rb
set :shared_children, [app_path + "/logs", "vendor"]
set :use_composer,    true
set :update_vendors,  true
set :vendors_mode,    "install"
```

But Capifony seems to reinstall the whole vendor set instead of relying on the standard `composer install` mechanism (it takes years)

As stated [here](http://capifony.org/cookbook/speeding-up-deploy.html), the suggested way to speed up the deployment is to copy vendors each time, but I don't want/need this since I can retrieve them from `composer.lock`.

Am I missing something ?

What is the standard way to run this `composer install` for each `cap deploy` without reinstalling the whole thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is define `use_composer` as true. Regarding your code, you should omit `update_vendors` or define it to false.

```
set :use_composer, true
set :update_vendors, false
```